# Reg exp javascript validation for name,(),% being removed from name field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to validate name field in javascript using reg exp where error message needs to be given if number and special character like **~`** are entered. I have used the below code :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ll", function(ll, element) {
   if (ll == null) {return false;}
   return this.optional(element) || ll.match(/^[^0-9~`^|]*$/);
}, "name  invalid");
```

Above code work fines but when we enter **ll()ss%%** in the name field it automatically removes *()* and *%* and takes only *llss* when form is submitted. We are using jquery and ui-dform-text  for the element.